# FatalExecutionEngineError in C# code

Tags: c#

I'm working with a finger print device where I'm capturing finger prints using C# wrappers. Before I can capture finger prints, I need to initialize the device using device's APIs. The device initialize API and set mode API gets executed sucessfully for the first time and I'm able to capture fingerprints. In second iteration, I dont initialize the device as it is already initialized and I call set mode API again with a different parameter. I think this API gets executed successfully as it returns OK status. If I try to execute any C# statement after calling this API it is leading to FatalExecutionEngineError as shown below:

---

```
nRc = APIWrapper.CG4_M_Capture_SetMode(
                                m_nDeviceId,
                                imageType,
                                m_ImgResolution,
                                m_bAutoCapture,
                                m_bAutoContrast,
                                &m_nFullImgWidth,
                                &m_nFullImgHeight,
                                &m_nBaseRslnX,
                                &m_nBaseRslnY
                                );

if(nRc != 0)      <<<<<<<<<<<<<--------- (FatalExecutionEngineError)

LogError(nRc);
```

> Error : The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x6c96eb22, on thread 0x13d0. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

---

nRc varaible contains CG4_STATUS_OK which indicates the API has been executed successfully. I cross-checked the parameters passed to this API and they are correctly passed. The parameters passed to this API are also inline with programmer's manual. I'm not sure how to further analyze this issue. Could you please let me know what more I can do to debug this issue as I'm new to C# environment.

Comment: This seems to be on the API's side. Read the documentation on reinitializing the same instance.

Comment: Please post the original C-syntax signature of the method you're calling. If it's COM then please post the IDL definition or signature, in addition to your C# P/Invoke signature. It's possible you're doing marshalling incorrectly, especially as it looks like you're passing values in by-reference. Why are you using the address-of `&` operator instead of using automatic `out`/`ref` marshalling? Is any of this contained within an `unsafe` block?

Comment: The function where CG4_M_Capture_SetMode gets called is made unsafe. The signature of this function is :   public override unsafe void StartScan(SCANMODE scnMode, IntPtr hWnd, List<fingerTypes> fingerList, bool resetDevice). I'm using address-of operator because SetMode API call is made according to programmer's manual, we need to use address-of operator..